# How can i integrate ethereum or waves platform wallet on my site?

Tags: blockchain

i want next things to be on my site:
1. For some actions made by users on my site i want to pay them a reward with a tokens.
2. Users must have an ability to transfer tokens from one account to another.
3. Users must have an ability to withdraw this tokens or convert them into cryptocurrency.
The question is, how can i do it? 
Maybe somebody already did something like this on his own site.
Hope you will help me and sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should use the [web3 JavaScript API](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API). 
Users visiting your site should have the plugin [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) (there are other ways but this is the most popular and simple). The MetaMask plugin allows them to import their accounts. You can extract all the information you need (like accounts addresses) by MetaMask plugin using the Javascript API.

1. After you extract their accounts you can send them over to your custom server and reward them by making transactions to your smart contract where you exchange tokens.
2. Every user has associated eth accounts. They can make transaction to the smart contract to exchange tokens with other users (similar to how you reward them)
3. They exchange tokens for etherium by invoking the corresponding method of your custom smart contract which estimates the value of the token according to how you value them in your smart contract and based on the token value in ethers you deduct that value from the ethers which are deposited in the smart contract address and then transfer the ethers to the user etherium account.